# RecyclerView not calling getItemCount

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-viewholder

I've investigated several SO answers on this question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809524/recyclerview-not-call-oncreateviewholder), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066340/recyclerview-not-displaying), [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992929/recyclerview-not-calling-oncreateviewholder-or-onbindview)) and none of the proposed solutions have worked.  My problem is that my RecyclerView list items aren't being displayed. I've set breakpoints in MessengerRecyclerAdapter, onCreateViewHolder, onBindViewHolder, and getItemCount and only the first one is ever called.  While in a breakpoint I've entered the expression evaluator and executed

```
MessengerRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount();
```

And received the expected answer of 20. The RecyclerView itself takes up the intended content area as demonstrated by the screenshot below (I turned the RecyclerView magenta to highlight the space it occupies).

[image: RecyclerView location]

My RecyclerView XML code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/thread_list"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:name="com.jypsee.jypseeconnect.orgPicker.MessengerListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context="com.jypsee.jypseeconnect.orgPicker.MessengerListFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_messenger_cell"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My RecyclerView Cell XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    android:textColor="@color/blueText"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    android:textColor="@color/darkText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My ListFragment class:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    List<DummyContent.DummyItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i<20; i++){
        DummyContent.DummyItem item = new DummyContent.DummyItem(i.toString(),"Content","Details");
        items.add(item);
    }

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messenger_list, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.thread_list);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerAdapter = new MessengerThreadRecyclerAdapter(items, mListener);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);
    mRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return view;
}
```

My Adapter class:

```
public class MessengerRecyclerAdapter
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessengerRecyclerAdapter.MessageThreadHolder>{

private final List<DummyItem> mValues;
private final RecyclerViewClickListener mListener;

public MessengerRecyclerAdapter(List<DummyItem> items, RecyclerViewClickListener listener) {
    mValues = items;
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public MessageThreadHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_messenger_cell, parent, false);
    return new MessageThreadHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageThreadHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
    holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).id);
    holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).content);
    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.recyclerViewListClicked(v, position);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mValues.size();
}

public class MessageThreadHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final View mView;
    public final TextView mIdView;
    public final TextView mContentView;
    public DummyItem mItem;

    public MessageThreadHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
        mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
    }
}
```

}

As you can see I've set the linearLayout orientation to vertical and set the layout manager, which were the 2 most common solutions. I'm really at a loss as to what to try next, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Write your code in onViewCreated() method instead of onCreateView(), in onCreateView you should only return your inflated view and rest of code must be in onViewCreated.

Comment: Show your `fragment_messenger_cell.xml` and try `mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in previous Answer edit. The issues was in your xml. The main reason it was not showing was because, **You were trying to add the fragment using include tag instead of fragment tag** thus respective fragment class was never getting called on the fragment layout being added to your activity. 
Below is the code you needed to add the Fragment correctly.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/message_thread"
        android:name="com.jypsee.jypseeconnect.orgPicker.MessengerThreadListFragment"
        layout="@layout/fragment_messengerthread_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_messengerthread_list" />
```

And your fragment layout should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".orgPicker.MessengerThreadListFragment">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/thread_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the screenshot of working [image]

Comment: @JamesJordanTaylor I have updated my answer and sent you the email. please check

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I was missing calling notifyDataSetChanged() after setting list in adapter.